# Iniciante em C! Duvida!

Tags: c

Olá! Alguém poderia me ajudar nessa questão aqui! (Linguagem C)

"Escreva um algoritmo que leia 15 números e escreva quantos números maiores que 30 foram digitados."

Como seria o algoritmo em C para responder isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olá,

A comunidade SO não costuma gostar de perguntas que parecem enunciado de questões, porque mostra que você não tentou pesquisar nada antes de vir aqui.

Você sabe o básico de C?

A biblioteca padrão para funções de leitura e impressão é a stdio

Você pode incluí-la no início do programa com

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Isso te dará acesso à funções como printf e scanf.

Para ler um inteiro, você precisa declarar um inteiro e uma chamada de scanf.

```
int x;
scanf(" %d", &x);
```

O operador & passa para o scanf o endereço de x, local onde será armazenado um inteiro ("%d") lido.

Você sabe como fazer um laço em C?

```
int i;

for(i=0; i < 15; i++) {

    printf("Estou na iteração %d desse laço\n", i);

}
```

Esse trecho irá iterar 15 vezes, só imprimindo isso.
"\n" adiciona uma quebra de linha.

Você também vai precisar de comparações.

```
int x = 1;
int count = 0;
if( x > 30 ) {

    count += 1;

}
```

Esse trecho irá adicionar 1 em count se x for maior que 30.

Juntando tudo:

```
#include <stdio.h.>

int main(void) {

    int i = 0, count=0, x;
    for(i=0; i < 15; i++) {
        scanf(" %d", &x);
        if( x > 30 ) {
            count +=1;
        }
    }
    printf("%d numeros maiores que 30\n", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Valeu Gabriel! Muito obrigado! Sobre a minha pergunta, como você acha que eu poderia a ter postado?

Comment: Se eu resolvi sua dúvida, por favor, marque como correta. A sua postagem poderia ter sido algo do tipo: "Estou com dúvidas para montar um laço em C, qual a sintaxe?"

Comment: Algo mais específico do que: "qual é o algoritmo?"

Comment: @DexterMayhew confira o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e [este guia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sobre como fazer uma boa pergunta.

Comment: @DexterMayhew , por favor leia o conteúdo do link a seguir e então você vai entender porque a sua pergunta não condiz com a política do site: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5486/132